# Excel 2013 Workout Tracker - Insert Row and Auto Fill Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a coach, and I am building a workout tracker for athletes, but I am not an Excel expert.

Since the number of exercises can change day-to-day, I need to be able to automatically fill formulas when inserting a new row at the end ***or*** in the middle of the used range (see picture below with sample numbers)

[image: workout tracker].

Because there are going to be a lot of calculations in columns when this is finished, I don't want to have to manually fill down the formulas in each range.  I would use tables but Excel won't let me insert a row if more than 1 table is using that row for some reason...

Is there any way to do this?

I need to keep everything on 1 sheet because each sheet will be 1 month of training, and I need to keep the horizontal structure because the empty space below in the screen shots will end up being used in other ways.

Comment: If you can't use tables, the easiest way is to click in the cell with your formula, then hover over the bottom right until the cursor tuns into a cross. Click and drag down as many rows as you need, and this will autofill the cells with your formula.

Comment: When inserting your row, do you really want a row inserted in all tables?

Comment: Excuse the long delay please! tax time...Thank you for your replies! I am totally new to this forum.

**jrichall**--I appreciate the reply, but I don't want to have to click and drag. I will be building a larger more complicated workbook than the picture indicates, I'd rather have it automated. 

**Mark**--All tables directly horizontal to each other, Yes I do--the tables to the right are dependent on the first one: they perform calculations on that data. The 1st table has the data input, the 2nd/3rd tables have calculations based on that input